# Calculate balance amount in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7rGCiqw7)**

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    stock_date DATE,
    inbound_quantity INT,
    outbound_quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO inventory
(stock_date, inbound_quantity, outbound_quantity
)
VALUES 
('2020-01-01', '900', '0'),
('2020-01-02', '0', '300'),
('2020-01-03', '400', '250'),
('2020-01-04', '0', '100'),
('2020-01-05', '700', '500');
```

---

**Expected Output**:

| stock_date | inbound_quantity | outbound_quantity | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 900 | 0 | 900 |
| 2020-01-02 | 0 | 300 | 600 |
| 2020-01-03 | 400 | 250 | 750 |
| 2020-01-04 | 0 | 100 | 650 |
| 2020-01-05 | 700 | 500 | 850 |

**Query:**

```
SELECT
iv.stock_date AS stock_date,
iv.inbound_quantity AS inbound_quantity,
iv.outbound_quantity AS outbound_quantity,
SUM(iv.inbound_quantity - iv.outbound_quantity) OVER (ORDER BY stock_date ASC) AS Balance
FROM inventory iv
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1;
```

---

With the above query I am able to calculate the balance of in`bound_quantity` and `outbound_quantity` in PostgresSQL. 
However, when I run the same query in `Amazon-Redshift` I get this error:

> Amazon Invalid operation: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause;
> 1 statement failed.

How do I need to change the query to also make it work in Redshift?

Comment: It's interesting that postgres allows this at all. It's making some assumptions on your behalf that redshift doesn't and I have to say that I'm not a fan of postgres' behavior on this one. You'll need to define your frame like: `SUM(iv.inbound_quantity - iv.outbound_quantity) OVER (ORDER BY stock_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Balance` That additional information says that when ordered, only sum the rows from the beginning of the set to the current row (and don't sum any rows that occur after the current row).

Comment: It's likely that `CURRENT ROW` is given by assumption by the frame specification if you don't declare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error speaks, you need to add the frame specification clause, namely the `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` into your window function.

```
SELECT iv.stock_date AS stock_date,
       iv.inbound_quantity AS inbound_quantity,
       iv.outbound_quantity AS outbound_quantity,
       SUM(iv.inbound_quantity - iv.outbound_quantity) OVER (
           ORDER BY stock_date ASC 
           ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
       ) AS Balance
FROM inventory iv
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1;
```